# rotating x letter in Extraction word but getting error

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

i am making a website that name is **Extraction**

i want to add animation like this gif

https://www.inxternal.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/mini.gif

I try it but my result not good check this link

[my try](https://www.canva.com/design/DAFS8gCyq9w/zaD4vSE9UVvktmHNYbAKyg/watch?utm_content=DAFS8gCyq9w&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=link&utm_source=publishsharelink)

```
 <h1 class="name"> X  </h1>
```

```
 
  .name {
            /* rotate clock wise and anti-clock wise with zoom effect
            like first rotate clock wise 
            ans then anti-clock wise 
            */
           
            /* animation-timing-function: linear; */
            animation: rotate 1s   infinite ;
        }
        @keyframes rotate {
            0% {
                transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
            }
            50% {
                transform: rotate(180deg) scale(-0.5); 
            }
           
            100% {
                transform: rotate(180deg) scale(0.5);
            }
        }
```

Comment: try to adjust your animation time, 4s should to what you expect

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that to make it smooth like in the gif you sent you should you ease or a custom cubic-bezier (the simple way to make one is through this tool https://cubic-bezier.com/).

Also, I think you need to add more keyframes to make it rotate both clock wise and anti-clock wise.

Comment: I tried but still getting the same effect please help me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).